# How to prevent div from pushing others div when there is long content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hi guys need your guidance on CSS layout,

I quite new to CSS and Flexbox and try to build a simple layout.

Issue that I am facing is, how to prevent the long content inside pre tag from pushing others div

Before long code content:

[image]

After long code content:

[image]

From the screenshot, there is 2 problems:

1. The left sidebar and right sidebar was pushed by the main content
2. The pre content should wrap into scrollable similar to StackOverflow

I was thinking to set max-width on pre tag and use overflow: scroll, but how do I set the max-width based on the parent container? (parent container is fluid)

Here is the codepen:

https://codepen.io/cyberflyx/pen/VwaxNWp

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Learn Max Width</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="flex justify-between">
    <div class="left-sidebar bg-blue p-4">
      <h3>This is Left Sidebar</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="main-content flex-1 bg-yellow p-4">
      <div class="content-body">
        <h3>Main Content</h3>
        <p>This is long content between all of use</p>
        <pre>
        Sep 10 17:10:30 api-testapp-03 testapp.commands.generate_logs.run_test(): NOTICE: Got events:/home/m/app/testapp/queues/test.queue 


      </pre>

      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="right-sidebar bg-red p-4">
      <h3>This is Right Sidebar</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.justify-between {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left-sidebar {
}

.content-body {

}

.right-sidebar {
}

pre {
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 10px;
/*     overflow: scroll; */
/*   max-width: 500px; */
}

.flex-1 {
  flex: 1 1 0%;
}

.p-4 {
  padding: 4px;
}

.bg-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.bg-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.bg-red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the middle `<div>` container, it's the the `<pre>` element that spans the length of its content. To wrap the the text use the [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) CSS property:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

pre {
  background-color: pink;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 4px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.p-4 {
  padding: 4px;
}

.bg-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.bg-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.bg-red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex justify-between">
  <div class="left-sidebar bg-blue p-4">
    <h3>This is Left Sidebar</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content flex-1 bg-yellow p-4">
    <div class="content-body">
      <h3>Main Content</h3>
      <p>This is long content between all of use</p>
      <pre>
        Sep 10 17:10:30 api-testapp-03 testapp.commands.generate_logs.run_test(): NOTICE: Got events:/home/m/app/testapp/queues/test.queue 
      </pre>

    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="right-sidebar bg-red p-4">
    <h3>This is Right Sidebar</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to add a scrollable `<pre>` by adding `overflow: auto;` to the `<pre>` tag. Then Since there are 3 child elements under the flex, I added a `max-width` of `33%` to all the child elements of `flex` class. This is the final css

```
.left-sidebar, .main-content, .right-sidebar {
    max-width: 33%;
}

pre {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The key is to set the max-width of 33% to all the child elements. This splits the parent element into 3 equal (almost) fixed parts.

Also note that the `justify-content: space-between;` might add some space between the 3 divs. If you don't want to have space between them, just add your `flex-1` class to the  `left-sidebar` and the `right-sidebar` `div` elements

Comment: Thanks. Is it a standard practise to always set the width / max width of the sidebar and let the content container take the available width?

Comment: `flexbox` will automatically distribute the parent container width equally among the child elements. This is the default behavior of `flexbox`. However, in your case, I think the `pre` element is causing the `flexbox` to distribute the width unevenly. I'm setting the `max-width` property here just to "override" this behavior.

Comment: I don't get why the main-content should have a max-width of 33%?